# What features do you need the most in Adobe Air?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, air

I recently started to develop using Flex 3 and Adobe Air and I wanted to know what features you want to be in futures releases of Adobe Air ?
The ones that I miss are:

- Cross-systems way of launching a local file (shellExec) right from an Air application (although you can do this using workaround at least under Windows)
- Ability to setup dynamic paths for Embed statement (e.g. *Embed[(variable+"/path/to/file")]* ). I didn't find any way to do this properly.
- Some way of setting Flex object's positions with absolute values from CSS (that sounds more Flex related by the way)

Don't hesitate to add your workarounds to theses limitations if you know somes.

Comment: Embedding is done at compile time, so allowing variables there doesn't really make sense.

Comment: So.. that said you want to do somethink like "skinning" support for your app , how do you setup a particular folder for every skin's assets without changing hardcoded paths ? I want to do this and EMBED the assets but I can't find any solutions..

Answer (score 2):

- Ability to call out to native code - you currently have to ship a server written in another language and make calls to that to do anything more than Air gives you.
- Modal windows. There's a hack you can do which involves setting Application.application.enabled = false, setting dialog.nativeWindow.alwaysInFront = true and then re-enabling the application when the dialog closes, but this is long-winded and doesn't disable any native menus you may have! It's crazy that something so simple is made so difficult.
- A usable way to set the application's icon. I spent 2 hours trying to do this the other day and gave up after persistent "303" errors that gave me no idea of what I was doing wrong. Again, really basic stuff.

Answer (score 0):

"Call native code", "Modal windows", agree-agree. 
loadLibrary would be really great :)

ps.: 

   if we can not have this features in AIR, if would be awesome to have an opportunity 
   to embed flash(AIR) graphics engine into your own app. in that case we'll get 
   great performance improvement and liberty of choice what to write (not 
   only small gadgets).